# Ant Design: Table Need to place "expandable row" before parent children

Tags: reactjs, antd

Expected:
Expandable row should be below children

Actual:
Expandable row currently placed above record children

```
<Table
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={data}
  expandable={{
    rowExpandable: (record) => {
      console.log('record ', record);
      return record.children ? true : false;
    },
    expandIcon: ({ expanded, onExpand, record }) => {
      if(!record.children || record.children.length === 0) return null;
      return expanded ? (
        <DownOutlined onClick={e => onExpand(record, e)} />
      ) : (
        <RightOutlined onClick={e => onExpand(record, e)} />
      )           
    },
    expandedRowRender: (record, index, indent, expanded) => {
      console.log(record, index, indent, expanded);
      return <Button>Save</Button>;
    }
  }}/>
```

Git Issue raised: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/31830

Reproducible link: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-03w6r

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, where do you expect the expanded row to render? At the bottom of the whole table?

Comment: Hi @slideshowp2, Not at the bottom of the whole table. Wanted expandable row after children of each row. Please check image attached (updated question).